# MachineKey.Unprotect Causing Exception When Referenced From .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am referencing a .NET Framework 4.7.2 class library from an ASP.NET Core application. And the framework code includes `MachineKey.Unprotect`, which seems to cause the following error:

> Could not load type 'System.Web.Security.MachineKey' from assembly
>   'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Is this some kind of a limitation or is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement machineKey in ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46668192/how-to-implement-machinekey-in-asp-net-core-2-0)

Comment: @kapsiR Not really, because I am not trying to reimplement encryption in .NET Core. I need to use the class library as is.

Comment: Hi @John L,did my reply help you? If my reply have already solved your issue, please accept it as answer. About how mark it as answer, you could refer to [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). This will help other people who faces the same issue..If not,could you please follow up to let me know?

Answer (score 0):

Since the System.Web.Security isn't build with .NETStandard, we couldn't use it in the asp.net core application.

According to your description, if you want to decrypt the machine key encrypt value. I suggest you could try to use some third party library which implement the asp.net MachineKey.upprotect method. For example: [AspNetTicketBridge](https://github.com/dmarlow/AspNetTicketBridge/tree/14a1d16fb3a0f4a5372aa31619ac2e146f62748d). You could directly install it from [Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetTicketBridge/).

More details, you could refer to below test demo:

Protect the message in an asp.net application.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Label1.Text = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

        var message = "My secret message";

        var encodedMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

        var protectedMessage = MachineKey.Protect(encodedMessage);

        var protectedMessageAsBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(protectedMessage);

        Label2.Text = protectedMessageAsBase64;

    }
```

Machine key:

```
<machineKey compatibilityMode="Framework45" validationKey="xxx" decryptionKey="xxx" validation="SHA1" decryption="Auto" />
```

Unprotect the message in an asp.net core application:

```
        string validationKey = "machinekey value";
        string decryptionKey = "machinekey value";
        var message = "above base64 message";

        var convertFromBase64 = Convert.FromBase64String(message);
        var ticket = MachineKeyTicketUnprotector.Unprotect(convertFromBase64, decryptionKey, validationKey, "AES", "HMACSHA1", "User.MachineKey.Protect");

        var decodedMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ticket);
```

Result:

[image]

---

If you want to achieve using machinekey in asp.net core application, you could try to implement the source code from the .net Framework machinekey.cs. Details, you could refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46604101/7609093).